# MotionEventCompat functions are deprecated

Tags: android

I am trying to add an `onTouchEvent` to a `View`, but I then see the deprecation support on this link: https://developer.android.com/sdk/support_api_diff/26.0.0-alpha1/changes/android.support.v4.view.MotionEventCompat.html.

[image]

It says, they are all deprecated. So what code should be used to replace the `MotionEventCompat` functions?

Comment: Good question! Why the downvotes? People are sooo mean! I upvoted! ;)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You can instead use the `MotionEvent` object directly to achieve the same.

Please see the example & comparison as below:

```
public boolean onTouch(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    // previously you would do this
    final int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(motionEvent);
    // now you would do this
    final int action = motionEvent.getActionMasked();
}
```

I think you are confused, as some of the Android documentation has yet to update their sample code, so some of their sample code is still using the deprecated methods.

For more info, please read [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html).

Hope this helps.

Comment: MotionEvent doesn't have all of the same functions as MotionEventCompat though...

Comment: Android is dropping support on old devices. "You should use Support Library classes where possible to provide compatibility with devices running Android 1.6 and higher." https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector

Comment: Why does [Android doc](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector) page, still have deprecated functions in examples like MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event) ?

Answer (score 3):

I know it is an old question but, I had to refactor some code and, I had to update these deprecated functions.
It is easy to refactorize it, just do this:

- If you use constants like `MotionEventCompat.ACTION_MASK`, then replace them for `MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK`
- Every time you have something like `MotionEventCompat.getPointerId(ev, index);` do this instead: `ev.getPointerId(index);`

And that is all!
I will list a few more examples to be clearer:

- Replace `MotionEventCompat.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN` by `MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN`
- Replace `MotionEventCompat.ACTION_POINTER_UP` by `MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP`
- Replace `MotionEventCompat.getX(ev, pointerIndex);` by `ev.getX(pointerIndex);`
- Replace `MotionEventCompat.getY(ev, pointerIndex);` by `ev.getY(pointerIndex);`
- Replace `MotionEventCompat.getActionIndex(ev);` by `ev.getActionIndex();`

Also (not directly related to this question) I had to replace `VelocityTrackerCompat.getXVelocity(velocityTracker, mActivePointerId);` by `velocityTracker.getXVelocity(mActivePointerId);`

I hope this can help someone else in the future :)